# What is the recommended gc for a Spring Boot application compiled to native image

Tags: spring-boot, garbage-collection, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am testing native compilation with Spring Boot:
https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native

and I found the following documentation:
https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/MemoryManagement/

What is the recommended gc for a Spring Boot application?

Comment: You can try using G1GC with profile guided optimization 
https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/pedal-to-the-metal-high-performance-java-with-graalvm-native-image?source=:so:tw:or:awr:jav:::&SC=:so:tw:or:awr:jav:::&pcode=

Comment: G1CC is only available for GraalVM Enterprise

Comment: For CE you can try default GC with PGO